# Forge Viewer toolbar buttons not hiding on mobile phone screen

Tags: javascript, css, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I am trying to adjust the buttons to only show the navigation tools when the device is a mobile phone. I'm using the following code:

```
  viewer.toolbar.getControl('settingsTools').setVisible(false);
  viewer.toolbar.getControl('modelTools').setVisible(false);
  viewer.toolbar.getControl('navTools').setVisible(true);
  viewer.toolbar.getControl('navTools').getControl('toolbar-orbitTools').setVisible(true);
```

But then it will remove the visible buttons which were the SettingsTools and half of the modelTools. But it won't show the navTools.

[image]

In the HTML I see that the buttons are still giving a css tag `display: none`

[image]

How can I make this work?

EDIT:
I have changed the logic to directly change the CSS (display = none or block) as per this example http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2017/03/hiding-unwanted-toolbar-items-in-the-forge-viewer.html.

Using this causes the button to be arranged and styled weird. Is there a method I need to call to let the viewer update its outlining etc?

[image]

Comment: Apologizing for the late response. May I ask what version of the Forge Viewer you used is? Your codes work properly on my iPhone 6 with iOS 10.3.2 and Forge Viewer v2.14. Could you provide more detail information to me for the further debugging? Please remove any sensitive data of yours and your company before you send it to me. BTW, here are my screenshots for the codes: http://imgur.com/a/f7r0w

Comment: @EasonKang I'm using v2.13. I'm trying to fix it on Android devices. I'm using multiple listeners to set the values (also tried it with just one) [image](http://imgur.com/a/mh03a)

Answer (score 0):

I found that it also works properly on my Android 6.0 device with the Google Chrome and the viewer v2.13. I have no explanation for the visibility of the button control in your device.

If you can provide a reproducible case demonstrating that, I will gladly pass it on to the development team for analysis. Those following items should be in the reproducible case:

1. A **short** exact description of what you are trying to achieve. The behavior you observe versus what you expect, and why this is a problem.
2. A complete yet minimal sample source model to run a test in.
3. A complete yet minimal Forge app that can be run and debugged with a simple procedure to analyze its behavior live in the sample model.
4. Detailed step-by-step instructions for reproducing the issue, e.g. which element to pick, what command to launch etc.

If your reproducible case could not be posted here publicly, please send it to the `forge.help@autodesk.com` and **remove sensitive data or information before you send**.

Comment: Is it possible to have a working test model from you. I want to test if it is a model related issue or a implementation part. Our own model contains a lot of sensitive data so removing them would take a lot of time. Having a working model and test our implementation on that would be a way to check for model related issues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the sample model of the Revit called `rac_basic_sample_project.rvt` that could be downloaded from here [https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html].

Comment: Apologizing for the wrong url, here is the correct one: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html